# Getting Error Authorizing for Spotify in my "Testing" App

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, spotify, spotipy

Ok so I'm trying to implement `Spotify API` to my app just for testing but im keep getting (`spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client`) error (Full error message mentioned after the code) even though I've added the correct `client_ID` and `client_secret` (in my original code) and `redirect_uri` from the `Spotify Dashboard`, any solution for this?

```
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

birdy_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP'
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id = 'ABC', client_secret = 'XYZ',redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback/',))
results = sp.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = sp.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 588, in refresh_access_token        
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python Projects\SpotipyTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    results = sp.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 392, in artist_albums
    return self._get(
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 297, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 221, in _internal_call
    headers = self._auth_headers()
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 212, in _auth_headers
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 525, in get_access_token
    token_info = self.validate_token(self.cache_handler.get_cached_token())
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 380, in validate_token
    token_info = self.refresh_access_token(
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 596, in refresh_access_token
    self._handle_oauth_error(http_error)
  File "D:\Uni\Semester 6\AI\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 146, in _handle_oauth_error
    raise SpotifyOauthError(
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client
```

Comment: I tested code with my API keys and it works correctly. But if I even try to use wrong keys I can't get error which you get. Maybe it is only temporary problem with internet.

Comment: @furas that's weird because ive tried it like atleast 10/12 times even wiht all devices (on wifi) off and restarting the internet. Is there something wrong with maybe VSCODE or something?

Comment: this problem has nothing to do with VSCODE. It can be eventually problem with access to internet because it need connect with server, but as for me you use wrong `client_id, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`. Maybe you should login again to your developer dashboard and check check `client_id` `client_sercret` for your application - https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications/